# iBeacon: Is possible send small data to track from transmit?

Tags: iphone, ios7, xcode5, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

I am going to start a project code for iBeacon with iOS 7 and bluetooth 4.0.

http://www.appcoda.com/ios7-programming-ibeacons-tutorial/

Readied above link, i have coded it and tested . it is working fine . 
Created  two apps. One for transmit beacon and another for track beacon. 
How can send small data to track beacon from  transmit beacon. Small data is a ID of room. 
Is possible send small data to track from transmit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot send any other data from a device transmitting as a beacon to another device via the iBeacons protocol. However, if only want to know a room ID, then you should set this as either the `major` or `minor` value of the beacon (or a combination of those two values).

As an example, a large retailer might set:

- UUID: A single UUID for the retailer
- Major ID: Identifies the specific store that a beacon is located in
- Minor ID: Identifies the department that the beacon is in

If you wish to transmit more substantial data between two iOS devices, you'll probably want to look at something like Apple's [Multipeer Connectivity framework](http://nshipster.com/multipeer-connectivity/).

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/DavidSahakyan/LGBluetooth

here is a framework which will help you to work bluetooth 4